# Import Users into AD Using CSV & PowerShell - ExtensionAttribute2 Issue

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm trying to import users into AD, using a PowerShell script, and a CSV.

Here's my script (with names removed):

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "passwordhere" -AsPlainText -Force

Import-Csv .\adimport.csv | New-ADUser -AccountPassword $pass -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=<ouname>,OU=<ouname>,OU=<ouname>,OU=<ouname>,DC=<name>,DC=<name>,DC=<name>,DC=<name>' -Properties userPrincipalName | foreach { Set-ADUser $_ -UserPrincipalName "$($_.samaccountname)@<domainname>"}
```

And here's how my CSV looks:

```
Name    Username    SamAccountName  GivenName   Surname DisplayName Description Path    Enabled Postalcode  StreetAddress   City    Title   Office  Company extensionAttribute2 officephone
```

Everything works fine, the users are imported (into the correct OU), and all the information is updated, apart from extensionAttribute2.

Does anyone have know what I would need to change to get extensionAttribute2 in AD to import the information under extensionAttribute2, from the CSV, when running the script?

If anyone needs any more information, let me know.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To set an Extension Attribute, use this syntax:

```
 Set-ADUser –Identity $ThisUser -add @{"extensionattribute1"="MyString"}
```

You can also specify other attributes using the -OtherAttributes param for New-ADUser

So, integrating this into your code, I'm attempting to create the new user and also specify the Extension Attribute at the same time.

```
Import-Csv .\adimport.csv | New-ADUser -AccountPassword $pass -Enabled $true `
  -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
  -OtherAttributes  @{"extensionattribute2"=$_.extensionAttribute2}
```

Lemme know if this helps :)

Comment: Hi Fox - thanks for the reply. Just to check; add this straight on after the -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true ?

Comment: ie

New-ADUser -AccountPassword $pass -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -OtherAttributes  @{"extensionattribute2"=$_.extensionAttribute2}

Comment: You're exactly right!  All I did was wrap your command around to fit it into the 80 characters allowed here in StackExchange.

Comment: @FoxDeply

Okay, so I tried this, and this is the error message I got:

New-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'OtherAttributes'. The argument is null or an element of the
argument collection contains a null value.

+ ... herAttributes  @{"extensionattribute2"=$_.extensionAttribute2}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Comment: If it helps, I'm using extensionAttribute2 for working days. An example of what I have written under extensionAttribute2 on the CSV is;

Mon - Fri 9am - 5pm

Comment: Make sure that your CSV has values specified for everyone on the ExtensionAttribute2 column.  The error message says that it tried to add an ExtensionAttribute and the value was empty.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. I've updated the CSV, so that everyone has a value under the extensionAttribute2 column (just put the word daily), but I still get the error. Does the extensionattribute have to be set in a specific format? Or should any text do? Thanks again for your help - much appreciated.